# UIToolbar more and configure views?

Tags: cocoa-touch

Is there any way to change the UINavigationBar and the colors of the more and configure views of a UIToolbar?  I have an app with a black toolbar and black nav bars but the more view is now out of place.  Any way to make this match?

Is there any way to get ahold of the configure view to alter it?

NOTE: This question refers to the configure view not the more view itself.  There has been no answer to that yet.

Answer (score 0):

Get ahold of your UITabBarController instance.
Then you can access the "More..." controller.
`self.myTabBarController.moreNavigationController`

From a tabbar's UIViewController child you also have an implicit reference:
`self.tabBarController.moreNavigationController.navigationBar.barStyle`